# How to solve attenuation caused by filter coefficient quantization in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, finite-impulse-response

Before quantization of filter coefficient, it behaves well, but after quantization the amplitude drops to 0.52186, which is expected to be 1000(fig.1). But according to the amplitude response in filterDesigner(fig.2). The 200Hz wave shouldn't decrease so much after filtering. Could someone tell me why the abnormal attenuation happens? Why is it 0.52186?

[image: Fig.1 effect of filter]
Fig.1 effect of filter

[image: Fig.2 amplitude response]
Fig.2 amplitude response

Matlab code is as follows

```
N = 2000;
    f0=200;
    f1=800;
    fs=2000;
    n=1:N;
    y =1000*sin(2*pi*f0.*n/fs)+500*sin(2*pi*f1.*n/fs);
    Hd = filter_below500Hz;
    d = filter(Hd,y);
    figure(2)
    subplot(2,1,1)
    plot(y);
    title({['y，before filtering']});
    subplot(2,1,2)
    plot(d);
    title({['d，after filtering']});
```

Comment: Unrecognized function or variable `filter_below500Hz`

Comment: What is unclear to me, are you looking at the frequency response of the floating point coefficients of your filter or at the frequency response of the filter with quantized coefficients?

Comment: That is indeed very wrong. But we need to see the filter coefficients themselves and the actual process how you quantize them.